# How do I use delta-times to determine the speed of a frame-by-frame animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, spritesheet

I have a character spritesheet with 8 images. How do I animate it?

At the moment, the sprite changes to a different image every frame, which makes the animation speed vary with framerate.  I have a delta time that calculates the time in ms between each frame.  Is there a smart way to make sprite animations use it?

I'm using JavaScript and canvas on my own engine, for practice.

Comment: What are you using to make the game? any engine or framework?

Comment: I'm writing the game in Javascript using canvas. I'm not using any framework or engine currently, but I'm trying to create my own engine with this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming pseudo code (in my example I use lua code) , and an anim class , consider the following anim update (using delta time dt) called in your update or draw cicle (it depends on engine..)

```
function anim:update(dt)
    if anim.started then
        anim.accum = anim.accum+dt          
        while anim.accum > anim.frameTime then
            anim.accum = anim.accum-anim.frameTime
            if anim.aType=="loop"then
                anim.curFrame=(anim.curFrame+1)%anim.nFrames                
            end
        end
    end
end
```

where `anim.accum` is an accumulator initilized to zero. `anim.frameTime` is the time (ms?) of each frame.(i.e: to increase anim speed reduce `anim.frameTime`). `Anim.curFrame` is current frame index (I leave to you how to recover a frame from your spritesheet, given an index, cause it depends on your spritesheet logic). `anim.nFrames` is animation total frames number.

Edited : thanks to Jon comment

Comment: `if` should maybe be `while` in case of large `dt`

Answer (score 0):

If you measured the `time` in ms from the start of the animation, the formula would be:

```
var frame_nr = Math.floor(FPS * time / 1000);
```

This way if your `time` was say 500 [ms] and your `FPS` was 60, the `frame_nr` would be 30.
You'd need to handle the case when the `frame_nr` exceeds your animation's length.

If you wanted the animation to loop, you could use the modulo operator:

```
var frame_nr = Math.floor(FPS * time / 1000) % frames.length;
```

So at half a second and 60 FPS and 30 frames long animation, the `frame_nr` would wrap back to 0.

Otherwise, if the animation was to be played just once, before you used a `frames_nr` to refer to an actual frame, you'd have to test for:

```
if (frame_nr < frames.length)
    draw_frame(frames[frame_nr]);
else
    ... // animation ended
```

Finally, to measure `time` you'd have to initialize the variable to 0 when your animation starts, and then at each frame accumulate the delta you already have available.